# archive manager

Tags: software-recommendation, mount

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [archieve manager does not archieve files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106104/archieve-manager-does-not-archieve-files)

The archive manager does not archive files and gives an error message during the archive.

```
Archive: /home/roland/Downloads/InstallWoW.exe
[/home/roland/Downloads/InstallWoW.exe]
End-of-central-directory signature not found. Either this file is not
a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive. In the
latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
the last disk(s) of this archive.
zipinfo: cannot find zipfile directory in one of /home/roland/Downloads/InstallWoW.exe or
/home/roland/Downloads/InstallWoW.exe.zip, and cannot find /home/roland/Downloads/InstallWoW.exe.ZIP, period.
```

How can I archive games?

Comment: right click on file > compress > then you can

Comment: is that what u r asking

Comment: there is no compress option ..there is a option of extract to ..and i also try extracting but there is a same archieving error.:(

Comment: the file is of type DOS/Windows executable (application/x-ms-dos-executable)

Comment: delete one of your question , you got 2 question same

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> (shortcut)to open terminal window

```
tar cf ~/wow.exe.tar /home/roland/Downloads/InstallWoW.exe
```

wow.exe.tar will be in your home directory