# archive manager does not archive files

Tags: software-recommendation, compression

The archive manager does not archive files or games and gives the following **error:**

```
Archive:  /media/BA/setup.exe
[/media/BA/setup.exe]
End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
the last disk(s) of this archive.
zipinfo:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /media/BA/setup.exe or
/media/BA/setup.exe.zip, and cannot find /media/BA/setup.exe.ZIP, period.
```

Or if i open it using autorun prompt then gives an **error:** `Permission Denied`

How can I archive games or other applications in Ubuntu?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FileCompression

Answer (score 1):

I guess you tried to **unpack** this file. To **compress** it open the folder */media/BA* and rightclick *setup.exe*. Then choose `Compress...`:

[image]

Now you can set the options for the compressed file:

[image]

`Create`, ready.

If this doesn't work open `Archive Manager` via Dash. Click `Open` to add a file or just drag and drop it from `Nautilus` (file manager).

[image]

To compress it now choose `New`:

[image]

Hope it works as it does here!

Comment: there is no option of compress on setup ..there is extract to option which also gives error ..

Comment: Indeed! I found another solution and expanded the answer.